# Creating a "Array" of "Dictionary" in Swift

Tags: swift

```
var numDict = [String: Int]()
numDict = ["age": 2, "total": 3]

var numArray = [Int]()
numArray = [1,2,3,4]

var dictArray = [Dictionary]()  // Error: "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"
```

the last line cause Error.

How should I Create Array of Dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the types for the dictionary inside the array:

```
var dictArray = [[String:Int]]()
```

In long form this would be:

```
var dictArray = Array<Dictionary<String,Int>>()
```

Comment: Hey @drewag, if i use the second type of declaration, how can i add dictionary's to this by iterating over a JSON object ?

Comment: @Sashi both declarations semantically identical. You add dictionaries like an object to any other array. If are asking how to iterate through JSON in swift, I recommend you google it as there is a lot of discussion online about that